# How to get the type of protobuf message from the field descriptor?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am trying to get the type of a data member inside a protobuf message and call the appropriate message from it.

```
message ControlMessage{}
message AdminMessage{}
message ExecMessage{}

message IncomingMessage
{
  optional ControlMessage cmsg = 1 ;
  optional AdminMessage amsg   = 2 ;
  optional ExecMessage  emsg   = 3 ;
}
```

sample main()

```
void onMsg(const ControlMessage&){}
void onMsg(const AdminMessage&){}
void onMsg(const ExecMessage&){}

int main()
{
  IncomingMessage msg ;
  msg.mutable_cmsg() ;
  msg.mutable_emsg() ;

  auto metadata = msg.GetMetaData() ;
  auto reflection = metadata.reflection ;
  auto descriptor = metadata.descriptor ;

  std::vector<const FieldDescriptor*> all_fields ;

  reflection->ListFields( msg, &all_fields ) ;

  for(auto msgItr : all_fields)
  {
     // Somehow call the onMsg() overloads
     // for all the fields set inside the msg
     // msgItr is the FieldDescriptor
  }
}
```

Is it possible to call the onMsg() overloads for all data members set inside the msg? I have gone through the protobuf documentation but in vain.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: @StfKolev thats the main problem, I do not have object of the type that I want to deduce. I have pointer of FieldDescriptor, which is not related to the message.

Comment: You can't. Use index of a data member to calculate its type.

Comment: Alright, what does your FieldDescriptor has as fields? And why would you need that? You already have the fields into the reflection of the metadata. Like, you got fields into the reflection alongside the message itself. You can just use that.

Comment: @S.M. when I get the index as an integer, there is no mapping provided by protobuf which maps [ index -> TYPE  ], if I had this, I guess the problem would have been solved? Am I correct that there is no such mapping provided by protobuf?

Comment: @StfKolev, I agree that handling can be done via reflection object, but the handling of different data members is to be done differently. First I need to know which type of data member it is, than I can apply the business logic on the individual data members.

Comment: @Jerry okay, here is the thing. As I think it, when you call `reflection->ListFields(msg, &all_fields);` you are actually filling the fields in, if I am correct, you can set a custom field to save the message type into a member of FieldDescriptor class. Once you do that, when you iterate over the fields, you will know each field's message type.

Comment: @StfKolev the FieldDescriptor is inbuilt class provided by protobuf library, it doesnt not have any data member that tells me the type of message, It's easy for POD type but not for custom messages. For custom message it gives back the type name, the string literal, instead I want the TYPE, I do not want to make mapping of own, as it is not very scalable and have to keep adding things forever.

Comment: @Jerry Take a look at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#FieldDescriptor.message_type.details

Comment: @StfKolev I did, I get a Descriptor pointer from calling message_type(), but even Descriptor doesnt tell me the type of the message, I agree I can access everything using the pointer, but first I need to know the type to know what to do with this message type. It provides me with the type_name, which I can make a check and call the corresponding code, but I didn't want to make this check by code, as it will require adding more checks when new members are added.

Comment: I have the same question. Have someone figured it out?